# Rudra prashna vs Rudraashtadhyayee

Tags: shiva, rudram

What is the difference between Shri rudra prashnah vs rudraashtadhyayee.I have seen few people chant the former where as later is also chanted with same popularity while performing rudrabhisheka. What is the difference between these two?